# in-text citation: How to get (Text, Citation) in one bracket

Tags: citing, brackets, format

I am trying to get the following:

....United States of America (USA, Example et al., 2017).
So I would like to have an abbreviation as normal text and a citation within one bracket unfortunately I cannot make it work.

I have tried:
\citep{{USA},example2017} but that results in (USA; (?)
I have tried different variations with and without ,

Can someone help me?
I am using the package \usepackage[natbibapa]{apacite}

Comment: You probably want to use the optional arguments to `\citep`, something like `\citep[USA,][]{example2017}`, but it's a little unclear what kind of "abbreviation" this is. Is this arbitrary text, or a `\citealias` abbreviation, or something else? A [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that) would help. What does `\citep{example2017}` by itself generate?

Comment: Thank you so much! \citep[USA,][]{example2017} this worked!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this may work if you are alright with hand-typing the ‘USA’ every time that you cite.

The cite command has a built in option that can be used, in my experience, for adding page numbers: `\cite[pagenumber]{source}`. So, in your example, if you were to type

`As per a study conducted in the United States of America \cite[U.S.A.]{example2017}...`

where `example2017` is the title of one of the entries in the .bib, then it should output:

`As per a study conducted in the United States of America (JohnDoe, 2017, U.S.A.)...`

I hope this helped.

Comment: Probably worth mentioning that `\cite` takes two optional arguments, and if you use both, the first one goes before the citation info and the second goes after. This is usually used like `\cite[see also][pagenumber]{citekey}`, but here it could be used to put the USA *before* the citation, `\cite[USA,][]{citekey}` to get (USA, JoneDoe, 2017) as in the OP's question.